# MySQL: is simple column value incrementing safe?

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE counter SET views=views+1
```

Is this query safe to use in InnoDB and MyISAM tables?

I remember, like 10 years ago, there was a bug (or "an unpleasant feature", if you prefer) - when there were 2+ hits of this query at the same time (2+ users visited the page at the same moment), the `views` value was reset to `0`.

Is this feature still there?

Answer (score 1):

This query is safe. Table (or rows in InnoDB format databases) is automatically locked when you execute an update query.